# How do webextensions internally communicate with the browser?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

Webextensios expose Javascript APIs under browser namespace. For example browser.topSites() in Javascript will return list of top visited sites as returned by the broswer.

I am interested how does this talk internally to browser object (presumably a C++ class) to call the appropriate method to get the list of top sites probably stored in some SQL Lite database.

So how does a call from Javascript map to appropriate C++ call architecturally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [JavaScript APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API) made for this purpose.

> JavaScript APIs for WebExtensions can be used inside the extension's
>   background scripts and in any other documents bundled with the
>   extension, including browser action or page action popups, sidebars,
>   options pages, or new tab pages. A few of these APIs can also be
>   accessed by an extension's content scripts (see the list in the
>   content script guide).

Update on comment:

Firefox has its own [SpiderMonkey: The Mozilla JavaScript runtime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey)

Comment: I know, but the question is how does JS communicate to browser C++ implementation?

Comment: That is the engine for parsing/compiling javascript. Not sure that handling of webextensions api would happen there?

Comment: @freediver I am not sure what you are asking. Extensions are written in JavaScript and there are API made for specific functions of the browser. Browser reads them and then both API functions and JavaScript are translated to C++ via SpiderMonkey. What else are you asking? There is no direct interaction between extension and C++ code of the browser since JavaScript ad API need translation the same way C++ needs translation before being converted to machine code binary.